# How to set different colors for lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot generated in R. How can I set the different colours for the lines? (`scale_color_manual(values = c('green', 'red'))` doesn't work

```
library(svars)
library(ggplot2)

data(USA)

reduced.form <- vars::VAR(USA, lag.max = 10, ic = "AIC" )
structural.form <- id.ngml(reduced.form)

counterfactuals <- cf(structural.form, series = 1)
plot(counterfactuals)
```

Comment: Are you hoping for a ggplot2 solution? It looks like you're using the base R `plot` function rather than a ggplot syntax. Filling in your example with the plotting code you've already got will give us a better idea of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize your plots using `ggplot2` you need to perform some manipulation taking your data out from `counterfactuals`.

```
library(tidyverse)

rbind(cbind(counterfactuals$counter, type = 'Counterfactual'), 
      cbind(counterfactuals$actual, type = 'Actual')) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Time = rep(index(counterfactuals$actual), 2)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Time, type)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Time, value, color = type) + 
  geom_line() + facet_grid(name~.) + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]